# R voice-recording

Tags: r, voice-recording

### Voice-recording problem in R

I've been trying to write a code which would record sound from microphone in R. I found function *record {audio}.* and used example shown in function description ( [here :](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/audio/record.html) ). However it works only for  first one time, I can see the result, plot it, but when I try to record second time program just freezes. Whole console needs to be restarted. I tried on a few computers (with diffrent OS) but with the same result. Did anyone have the same problem? Or is there any other way to record voice in R? It is going to be a part of voice-recognition system. 

Edit. There is also one thing that I skipped. The code I'm using is shown below. This is exactly the same as in example in documentation. Even though, the play fucntion 
doesn't work.

```
x <- rep(NA_real_, 16000)
# start recording into x
record(x, 8000, 1)
# monitor the recording progress
par(ask=FALSE) # for continuous plotting
while (is.na(x[length(x)])) plot(x, type='l', ylim=c(-1, 1))
# play the recorded audio
play(x)
```

Comment: You're clearly using it wrong and didn't bother to tell us anything useful in helping you determine what. For instance, some code would be nice. Failing that, read the documentation and compare what it says to what you think it's doing.

Comment: Could you include the snippet you are using? (with the multiple recording)

Comment: I don't know that package, but it sounds like you need to turn off an open data stream (the recording channel).

Comment: It's simplified example: x <- rep(NA_real_, 16000) record(x, 8000, 1) plot(x), however when I use the whole code shown in example, effect is the same

Answer (score 2):

Both `play` and `record` return asynchronously. I can imagine the second `record`-call is being called before completion (causing the audio device to be in-use), and perhaps even the `where`-channel being in use because of that.

Possible fixes include:

- Sleeping some time between the two recordings
- Reinitializing the `where`-part in `record`
- ...